# Is Boost.Python compatible with multiprocessing?

Tags: c++, boost, multiprocessing, boost-python

I want to use my C++ code with Python's `multiprocessing` so that my C++ code is called from different processes in parallel. The code does not save any state and no memory sharing is required between the different processes. I decided to use Boost/Python to allow my C++ library to be imported into Python.

However, this [FAQ](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/python/doc/html/faq/is_boost_python_thread_aware_com.html) says that Boost/Python is not compatible with multiple interpreters. I am trying to understand what this means exactly. Specifically, does this means that calling my C++ code through Boost/Python with `multiprocessing` would be problematic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple processes don't require more than 1 interpreter per process.

Also, the way you describe the situation is that you use a native module from Python. In that case Python is supplying the interpreter, anyways.

The way I understand the 1-interpreter limitation applies to embedding python from within C++ - a rather limited subset of the Boost Python features.

Comment: Ah OK, I misunderstood the documentation.